# Opening external url in lightbox

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink, lightbox

I have to create a lightbox and open the contents of an external url in there.
I am not allowed to change the existing code. At this moment it is a simple link to the page which will now have to load in a lightbox.

I have to write all the code myself, so no plugins such as colorbox.
I know how to open/close the lightbox. Just can't figure out how to load the content of an external url in there.

I hope you guys can help me:)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use load() method of jQuery. With the help of that method you can get content from another url and put as html in your lightbox.

```
$('#idofDiv').load('test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I think the url is not complete 'eepurl.com/q4rPD' and there should be no ;

Comment: Ah sorry, i mistyped the url. But the i made a mistake. i wanted to take the url out of my comment, but accidentally kept most of it.

Comment: yes jquery load method works with same domain. So you should put an iframe in your ligtbox and than change its src with jquery

Answer (score -1):

```
Lightbox 2 uses the jQuery framework. Load jQuery and the Lightbox javascript files in the proper order.

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>

Include the Lightbox CSS file.

<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Then use image from external url in this way

<a href="http://www.hyperlinkcode.com" rel="lightbox" ><img src="/images/sample-image.gif" border="0"></a>

The orignal url for this was

http://hyperlinkcode.com/images/sample-image.gif
```